# How to create a binary search tree from string?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree, search-tree

I tried to create a Morse encoder-decoder, and I have to do it with binary search tree (not with arrays). The following part supposedly takes a character array (which we created previously from a text file), and creates a search tree based on it.

In the btree_base character array we have the data, in the format:
*"(letter) (morse code)|(letter) (morse code)|"* etc. (eg. *e .|t -|z --..|* ...).

*Note: the string contains the data in such a way that by reading it from beginning to end, a balanced search tree would be created*

The creation of the binary tree is unsuccesful, which I know, because when I run the code, the btree_print function does not print anything on the console, and I found that's because a NULL pointer is passed to it.

My question is why is that and how to possibly solve the problem? Did I mess up with the pointers, or I need to use double indirection when I pass the root pointer? I don't really understand ** pointers, so I tried to avoid them.

```
typedef struct BinTree{
    char letter;
    char code[6];
    struct BinTree *left, *right;
} BTree;

BTree* add(BTree* root, char ch, char* code, int length){
    int i;
    char a;
    if (root == NULL) {
        BTree *new = (BTree*) malloc(sizeof(BTree));
        new->left = new->right = NULL;
        new->letter = ch;
        for(i=0; i<length; i++) new->code[i] = code[i];
        new->code[length] = '\0';
        return new;
    }

    a=root->letter;

    if (ch < a) root->left = add(root->left, ch, code, length);
    else if (ch > a) root->right = add(root->right, ch, code, length);

    return root;
}

void build(BTree* root, char* c, int length){
    int i, size=-1;
    char b, k[6];
    for(i=0; i<length; i++){
        if(size==-1) b=c[i];
        if(c[i]==' ') size=0;
        if(size!=-1 && c[i]!='|'){
            k[size]=c[i];
            size++;
        }
        if(c[i]=='|'){
            k[size]='\0';
            root=add(root, b, k, size);
            size=-1;
        }
    }
}

void btree_print(BTree* root){
    if(root == NULL) return;

    printf("%c %s\n",root->letter,root->code);
    btree_print(root->left);
    btree_print(root->right);
}

void btree_del(BTree* root){
    if(root==NULL) return;

    btree_del(root->left);
    btree_del(root->right);
    free(gyoker);
}

int main(){
    char btree_base[238];
    BTree* bin_root = NULL;

    build(bin_root, btree_base, 238);

    btree_print(bin_root);

    btree_del(bin_root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does `uj->letter = ch;` come from? Are you compiling with *warnings enabled* (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc, `-Weverything` for clang or `/Wall` (or `/W4`) for VS (`cl.exe`)?

Comment: Oh, sorry, 'uj' is supposed to be 'new', I corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're passing the root node to `build` by value, any changes made to it's value won't be reflected to the calling function. So as you've guessed you need to pass in a pointer to the root which would make it a `BTree **`.

```
build(&bin_root, btree_base, 238);
```

Then inside `build` when you want to access the root node you have to dereference `root` first by prefixing it with a `*` like this:

```
*root=add(*root, b, k, size);
```

`add` could also benefit from working like that, rather than returning the updated nodes. Which since `build` already has a `BTree **` means you'd just pass in `root` as is like this

```
add(root, b, k, size);
```